# jQuery round corner code for IE8 in standards mode?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, rounded-corners

I need a solution for round corners using javascript with or without jQuery in IE8 standards mode.

Comment: don't we all... rounded corners are such a PITA... hopefully someone gives a good answer to this

Comment: did you get an answer for this one?

Comment: Look at my answer below. The .htc file is the best solution and doesnt need javascript or JQ.

Answer (score 14):

This seems to [work](http://roundcorners.avinoam.info/#Home) in ie8 :

try it...

Update 11-10-2010: 
You can also try to include PIE.HTC and call that from your stylesheet. for more information see the [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/) website. It is a much better solution!

Comment: CSS3PIE works perfectly well in IE8 Standard mode. I am using it and it works.

Comment: If you would like to use PIE for hover images, you need to set your behavior to the base class/id.

Answer (score 9):

[jQuery corner()](http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/) seems to work correctly in IE8 standards mode. Seems to be the go-to corner plugin for jQuery, too.

Comment: dd_roundies offers more reliable rendering in my experience. jquery.corner's rendering can be weird if you dont have a solid background and even if you specify the cc/sc#.

Comment: The problem I came across with it was that it removed border css.

Answer (score 3):

I've had good luck with [dd_roundies](http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_roundies/). It doesn't use jQuery and it's a pretty small script.

Example usage from the site:

```
<script src="DD_roundies.js"></script>
<script>
/* EXAMPLES */

/* IE only */
DD_roundies.addRule('.roundify', '10px');

/* varying radii, IE only */
DD_roundies.addRule('.something_else', '10px 4px');

/* all browsers */
DD_roundies.addRule('.yet_another', '5px', true);
</script>
```

Comment: I went to DD_roundies example page. All examples were messed up in IE8 standard mode. I need something that will work in standard mode.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an htc file which works and is very popular.

[Curved Corner Border Radius Cross Browser with HTC file](http://www.htmlremix.com/css/curved-corner-border-radius-cross-browser)

[A file with the HTC file extension is a HTML Component file.](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fileextensions/f/htc-file.htm)