# IE8 has no rounded corner for latest jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-8

I am using the latest jquery and jquery-ui. I use most of the jquery buttons, datepicker, dialog, etc. None of them have rounded edges in IE8 either in compatibility mode or in non compatibility mode. However in firefox and chrome there are rounded corners. Is there anything that I need to include in the css of jquery which would apply the styles. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rounded Corners are a CSS3 Feature. IE 8 doesn't support CSS3. The earliest version of IE to support 'border-radius' is IE9.

If you're looking for a polyfill for older IE browsers check out [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/). I personally didn't have much luck with it, but I hear good things.

While IE8 is leaps and bounds better than it's previous versions, IE8 Has many deficiencies; particularily with it's support of features. Remember it's a 3 year old browser at the moment, it's a bit behind chrome/firefox which push updates to you almost on a weekly basis.

There's many polyfills for many features it or other browsers are missing, check out the [Modernizr Polyfill Wiki Article](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills) for information on tools you can use to fill the gaps. I will also suggest you carefully weigh the pros/cons of using a polyfill, sometimes you just don't need it. (Rounded corners aren't often website breaking, so you could just leave it out and carry on with your day)

Comment: That means the latest jquery uses the css3.

Comment: jQuery UI uses CSS3 in the default themes for thier elements because with IE8 and below the Square corners are still functional if not as asthetically pleasing.

Comment: @user525146 The jQuery UI CSS has been like that for a long time, at least 3 years.

Comment: I am new to jQuery so excuse my ignorance.

Comment: @user525146 That's fine, we're just making a point to distinguish where the problem is. It'll help you understand the technologies involved.

Answer (score 1):

You could use http://css3pie.com/ which emulates CSS3 features in old IE Versions. IE8 does not support a lot of CSS3 features like `border-radius`

Comment: I was kind of going through the documentation, I haven't gone through completely though. Just wanted to know, I would just add the path to .htc file in my css file and then the page would render with rounded corners etc., or are they any changes to override the jquery css ?

Comment: No you don't need to override the jQuery css. css3pie just looks up for unsupported features in the css.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to check out [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to emulate CSS3 features.  We've used it for that purpose (among others).

Comment: Just a FYI, Modnernizr itself isn't a polyfill, but it will detect when loading one is required. Modernizr reccomends CSS PIE as the polyfill for `border-radius` [See the wiki article](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills)

Answer (score 0):

They are a CSS3 feature which is not supported by IE.

- [jQuery round corner code for IE8 in standards mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/987270/1048572)
- [How to add CSS3 rounded corners with modernizr?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9892163/1048572)
- http://jonraasch.com/blog/css-rounded-corners-in-all-browsers
- http://css3pie.com/